# How can i get object from xml with specific tag value with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to get specific object from xml, i meant object with specific tag value. Here is sample xml:

```xml
<persons>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Jon</firstName>
            <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>1</number>
        </person_data>
        <body_parts>
            <body_part>Head</body_part>
            <body_part>Leg</body_part>
            <body_part>Nose</body_part>
        </body_parts>
    </person>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Kathy</firstName>
            <lastName>Carter</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>2</number>
        </person_data>
        <body_parts>
            <body_part>Head</body_part>
            <body_part>Palm</body_part>
            <body_part>Eye</body_part>
        </body_parts>
    </person>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Bob</firstName>
            <lastName>Burns</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>3</number>
        </person_data>
        <body_parts>
            <body_part>Leg</body_part>
        </body_parts>
    </person>
</persons>
```

And for example i want to get person with `<number>2</number>`. I do:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML;  
DECLARE @iterator int = 1
SET @xml = '<persons>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Jon</firstName>
            <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>1</number>
        </person_data>
    </person>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Kathy</firstName>
            <lastName>Carter</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>2</number>
        </person_data>
    </person>
    <person>
        <person_name>
            <firstName>Bob</firstName>
            <lastName>Burns</lastName>
        </person_name>
        <person_data>
            <number>3</number>
        </person_data>
    </person>
</persons>';  

select 
ordinate.value('(firstName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as firstName
,ordinate.value('(lastName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as lastName
from @xml.nodes('/persons[sql:variable("@iterator")]/person/person_name') xml_ordinates (ordinate)
```

And i get all the persons. But how can i navigate exactly to person with `<number>2</number>` and read it's name?

First i thought that `exists()` will help me, but it's just check that document contains person with `<number>2</number>` and i still get all the persons.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to check the value in the `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT p.p.value('(./person_name/firstName/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS firstName,
       p.p.value('(./person_name/lastName/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS lastName
FROM @XML.nodes('persons/person') p(p)
WHERE p.p.value('(./person_data/number/text())[1]','int') = 2;
```

Comment: @Lanu Thanks, its works great. But think that i miss important part in question. Each person has neasted list of objects and i used `@iterator` to select all the neasted objects. I updated sample xml in question. Can you look at it please?

Comment: I don't follow the "new" requirements, @KliverMax . If you want the values of `body_part` then make a call the `body_parts` node in the `FROM`. You should *not*, however, move the goal posts after receiving answers, as that is severely frowned upon. If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.